# options for questions in Watson conversation api

Tags: npm, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I need to get the available options for a certain question in [Watson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watson-developer-cloud) conversation api?

For example I have a conversation app and in some cases Y need to give the users a list to select an option from it.

So I am searching for a way to get the available reply options for a certain question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i had a conversation app and in some cases i need to give the users a list to select an option from it
so i was searching for a way to get the available reply options for a certain question

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer to the NPM part, but you can get a list of the top 10 possible answers by setting `alternate_intents` to `true`. For example.

```
{
  "context":{
    "conversation_id":"cbbea7b5-6971-4437-99e0-a82927607079",
    "system":{
      "dialog_stack":["root"
      ],
      "dialog_turn_counter":1,
      "dialog_request_counter":1
    }
  },
  "alternate_intents":true,
  "input":{
    "text":"Is it hot outside?"
  }
}
```

This will return at most the top ten answers. If there is a limited number of intents it will only show them.

Part of your JSON response will have something like this:

```
  "intents":[{
      "intent":"temperature",
      "confidence":0.9822100598134365
    },
    {
      "intent":"conditions",
      "confidence":0.017789940186563623
    }
```

This won't get you the output text though from the node. So you will need to have your answer store elsewhere to cross reference.

Also be aware that just because it is in the list, doesn't mean it's a valid answer to give the end user. The confidence level needs to be taken into account.

The confidence level also does not work like a normal confidence. You need to determine your upper and lower bounds. I [detail this briefly here](https://sodoherty.com/2016/09/05/handling-low-confidence-answers-in-conversation/).

> Unlike earlier versions of WEA, the confidence is relative to the
>   number of intents you have. So the quickest way to find the lowest
>   confidence is to send a really ambiguous word.
>
> These are the results I get for determining temperature or conditions.
>
> `treehouse = conditions / 0.5940327076534431`
>
> `goldfish = conditions / 0.5940327076534431`
>
> `music = conditions / 0.5940327076534431`
>
> See a pattern? So the low confidence level I will set at 0.6. Next
>   is to determine the higher confidence range. You can do this by mixing
>   intents within the same question text. It may take a few goes to get a
>   reasonable result.
>
> These are results from trying this (C = Conditions, T = Temperature).
>
> `hot rain = T/0.7710267712183176, C/0.22897322878168241`
>
> `windy desert = C/0.8597747113239446, T/0.14022528867605547`
>
> `ice wind = C/0.5940327076534431, T/0.405967292346557`
>
> I purposely left out high confidence ones. In this I am going to go
>   with 0.8 as the high confidence level.

Comment: Update to this answer. Current version of conversation now has absolute confidences.